# Different log levels in different places

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have a bunch of classes in `com.example`.  I want my logfile to capture debug logging and my console to capture info only.

I am using log4j2.

Here is my log4j2.properties file.

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs

# configure both the appenders 
# CONSOLE APPENDER
appender.console.type = console
appender.console.name = consoleAppender
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

# LOGFILE appender
appender.logfile.type = File
appender.logfile.name = logfileAppender
appender.logfile.fileName=extract.log
appender.logfile.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.logfile.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

logger.example.name = com.example
logger.example.level = debug
logger.example.additivity = true
logger.example.appenderRef.logfile.ref = logfileAppender
logger.example.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleAppender

# configure the loggers, starting from the root logger.
rootLogger.level = info
```

Which logs to debug at both.

I try this...

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs

# configure both the appenders 
# CONSOLE APPENDER
appender.console.type = console
appender.console.name = consoleAppender
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

# LOGFILE appender
appender.logfile.type = File
appender.logfile.name = logfileAppender
appender.logfile.fileName=extract.log
appender.logfile.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.logfile.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

logger.example.name = com.example
logger.example.level = debug
logger.example.additivity = true
logger.example.appenderRef.logfile.ref = logfileAppender

logger.info.name = com.example
logger.info.level = info
logger.info.additivity = true
logger.info.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleAppender

# configure the loggers, starting from the root logger.
rootLogger.level = info
```

But then nothing logs to console.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with this problem and when I add

```
 rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref=consoleAppender
 rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile
```

in the end of my log4j2. It's worked. The consoleAppender and RollingFile are the name of the `appender.console.name` and `appender.rolling.name`
 This is the end of my log4j2 configure:

```
loggers=console, rolling
logger.console.name=console
logger.console.level=info
logger.console.additivity=false
logger.console.appenderRef.console.ref=consoleAppender

logger.rolling.name=com.viking
logger.rolling.level=info
logger.rolling.additivity=false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile

rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.additivity=false
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref=consoleAppender
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile
```